# docker compose does not start the service inside the container

Tags: tomcat, docker, docker-compose, docker-entrypoint

I am actually having trouble in starting the tomcat service using the docker-compose.

Here is the `docker-compose.yml` I am using

```
version: '3.0'
services:
 tomcat:
  build: ./docker/cs_tomcat
  container_name: tomcat-container
  ports:
   - "8080:8080"
  entrypoint:
   - bash
  stdin_open: true
  tty: true
```

Here is the `Dockerfile` I created inside the cs_tomcat,

```
FROM tomcat:7.0.82-jre8
RUN apt-get update && apt-get -y upgrade
WORKDIR /usr/local/tomcat
COPY /cs.war /usr/local/tomcat/webapps/cs.war
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y dos2unix
EXPOSE 8080
COPY tomcat-users.xml /usr/local/tomcat/conf/
COPY file.xml /usr/local/tomcat/webapps/cs/conf/services/
COPY file2.xml /usr/local/tomcat/webapps/cs/conf/quartz/
COPY test.properties /usr/local/tomcat/conf/
ENV JAVA_OPTS="-Xms2G -Xmx2G"
# Copy Entrypoint script in the container
COPY ./docker-entrypoint.sh / 
ENTRYPOINT ["/docker-entrypoint.sh"]
```

When I run this docker file alone using the following, everything works fine

```
$ docker run -dit -p 8080:8080 app1 /bin/bash
```

When I use the following command to build and start the docker container 
using `docker-compose`, container gets started, but tomcat service did not get started.

```
$ docker-compose up -d --build
```

Here is my `docker-entrypoint.sh` file

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
 /usr/local/tomcat/bin/catalina.sh start 
 #wait
 #Extra line added in the script to run all command line arguments
exec "$@";
```

Can anyone see any mistakes here? Any help on this would be highly appreciable.

Comment: Can you also show us your docker-entrypoint.sh and also try running docker compose without the -d flag and show us the logs for the tomcat container

Comment: I updated my original  post with the docker-entrypoint.sh. When i run with following command,                                                                       
 $docker-compose up --build, i see that it got stuck saying that "Attaching to tomcat-container"  in the Docker Quick start terminal. This message stays for long time. If i do ctrl+c, container gets stopped

Comment: Are you able to build and run the container without docker compose?

Comment: Yes. I am able to build and run the container successfully.

Comment: I've just realized that you are overwriting your entry point in the docker compose file, just remove the entrypoint definition from your docker-compose.yml

Comment: I tried by removing the entry point in the yml file. Container got started successfully and it automatically exited as well. When i check the docker status, i see the state as "Exit 0".

Comment: `Usage:  docker run [OPTIONS] IMAGE [COMMAND] [ARG...]` So you *command* is `/bin/bash`? Don't know what this is doing, but maybe you should add this to your compose-file: `command: /bin/bash` ?

Comment: @Munchkin after adding the following line in the docker-compose.yml                      command: /bin/bash, i am able to start the container . Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You should be running Tomcat as the primary process in the container rather than `bash`. If you run tomcat in the backround then Docker will not be able to manage the service for you.

The [official image](https://github.com/docker-library/tomcat/blob/5a78361a9ce7ef48979acbcabe2acd9342d0168a/7/jre8/Dockerfile#L142) launches Tomcat with `catalina.sh run` so leave that in place by not overriding the command or entrypoint.

```
services:
 tomcat:
  build: ./docker/cs_tomcat
  container_name: tomcat-container
  ports:
   - "8080:8080"
```

Dockerfile

```
FROM tomcat:7.0.82-jre8
RUN set -uex; \
    apt-get update; \ 
    apt-get -y upgrade; \
    apt-get install -y dos2unix
WORKDIR /usr/local/tomcat
COPY /cs.war /usr/local/tomcat/webapps/cs.war
EXPOSE 8080
COPY tomcat-users.xml /usr/local/tomcat/conf/
COPY file.xml /usr/local/tomcat/webapps/cs/conf/services/
COPY file2.xml /usr/local/tomcat/webapps/cs/conf/quartz/
COPY test.properties /usr/local/tomcat/conf/
ENV JAVA_OPTS="-Xms2G -Xmx2G"
```

Then if you want to use bash shell, once the `tomcat` container is up, run

```
docker-compose exec tomcat bash
```

Comment: I tried already what you are suggesting. Issue i had was, my container get started and stopped immediately. To solve this issue, to make the container alive, i had to run this background process.

Comment: You need to fix the tomcat not running part, adding bash to keep a container in the started state won't help. What does `docker logs` report for the container? What do the other tomcat logfiles report?